# Как конвертировать int в минуты и секунды для TextView

Tags: android, строки, xamarin

Xamarin, Android

```
int Climb = 250;
```

Метод SetText выводит значение 250 (время в секундах)

```
_ComparePlaneLeftTextClimb.SetText(planesleft[e.Position].Climb.ToString(),
TextView.BufferType.Normal);
```

Как сделать, чтобы при выводе отображались минуты и секунды? Например вместо 250 (секунды) 4:10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы с временными интервалами нужно использовать `System.TimeSpan`

```
int сlimb = 250;
TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(сlimb);

string timeToShow = timeSpan.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
```

Comment: спасибо. А подскажите пожалуйста, как использовать строку timespan в моем методе SetText?

Comment: Вместо `planesleft[e.Position].Climb.ToString(),` использовать `timeToShow`, видимо

Comment: получилось. Только при варианте 4 минуты и 5 секунд отображается 4:5. Как можно сделать 4:05?

Comment: `timeSpan.ToString(@"mm\:ss");`